# xcframework XamarinForms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xcframework

In my case, I need to write a library for xamarin.forms which is based on native code. When I link to a project with xcframework from my XamarinForms.iOS.Sample I get the `Failed to resolve assembly` error.  This leads to the question whether can I add the xcframework to the xamarin forms project?

Any thoughts or other suggestions?

Comment: Xamarin.iOS has added support for .xcframework, and there is a simple here. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/pull/10046 You can  follow the progress of GitHub

Comment: this does not work for xamarin.forms @AdrainZhu-MSFT

Comment: It seems only works in VS for Mac and there isn't a detail documentation.You can try to post an issue on https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: I am working on VS for Mac. when I use xamarin.ios project, everything works fine. but as soon as I add a link to xcframweork from my xamarin.forms.ios, nothing works